# How to use the result of an Integration Procedure in a Condition View?

Tags: vlocity, omnistudio

I´m trying to use a Set Errors, in which I want it to appear if the result of the Integration Procedure is Null, but when I set it in the Conditional View, it didn´t works even if the result of the IP is null the error throws. How I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden formula field in the step that you want to show the error. Then after the step, use the SetError with that conditional view ( IPGetLeadDetails = null). Could you show me how did you managed to respond a null object from the IP?